# Why usort() not sorting array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

```
<?php

$items=[
    ['name'=>'a','require'=>[]],
    ['name'=>'b','require'=>['a']],
    ['name'=>'c','require'=>['b']],
    ['name'=>'d', 'require'=>['c']]

];

shuffle($items);

usort($items, function($a,$b){
    if(in_array($b['name'],$a['require'])){
        return -1;
    }
    if(in_array($a['name'],$b['require'])){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

print_r($items);
```

I'm expect that usort will rerturn me original sorted array, but each time i get different sorted arrays. What i doing wrong?

Comment: why you should need to do this? any specific purpose behind?

Answer (score 2):

Comparison functions need to fulfill some basic requirements, e.g. if `a<b` is 1, then `b<a` is -1.

Your function doesn't make sense, hence the unpredictable results.